# How to clear DropDown List within a With block in VBA?

Tags: excel, with-statement, vba

I have a With block that has a condition to see if a value exists in the drop down list.

```
   With wb.Sheets("BudgetLines").DropDowns("Drop Down 22")

    For Each c In refData.Range("G7:G" & LastRow_RefData).Cells

    Set Findo = wb.Sheets("BudgetLines").Cells.Find(c.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)






    If Findo Is Nothing Then
                Debug.Print "Name was not found."

                'DropDowns("Drop Down 22").Clear
            Else
               Debug.Print "Name found in :" & Findo.Address

                'Add title to drop down box
                .AddItem c.Value

            End If

    Next


End With
```

However, I want to clear the dropdown list completely. I have tried .Clear but it doesn't seem to pick up as this is in the With block.

Is there a way to do this within the With block?

Comment: Have you tried .ClearContents ?

Comment: Not much point to a `With` block for one member call.

Answer (score 1):

You need the `RemoveAllItems` function

```
Dim dd As DropDown
Set dd = wb.Sheets("BudgetLines").DropDowns("Drop Down 22")

With dd
    .RemoveAllItems
End With
```

The trick to seeing this was declaring a variable `Dim dd As DropDown`, which let me see the `RemoveAllItems` function when I `.`.

Comment: Ah! Thanks, thought it might of been clear or somthing!

Comment: @user3565164 please consider marking the answer as helpful (by upvoting) and accepted (by clicking the grey check-mark below the voting buttons) if it helped you solve your problem.  Your above comment suggests this is the case. This helps community to focus on other unanswered questions.